# Is there a simpler alternative to Jenkins?

Tags: .net, jenkins, continuous-integration, build-automation

I'm looking for a nightly/CI build server for a .Net project. Building it and running the NUnit tests is very simple. I've looked at Jenkins/Hudson, but the setup for it seems hard not just on a per-project basis, but for the initial set up my Arch Linux VPS with it.

Is there anything more simple then Jenkins or other open source build servers I can look into?

My project is open source so I'd also be open to (cheap/free) hosted solutions(ie, not hosted on my own server)

Comment: Teamcity hands down.....

Comment: what went south that made you dislike the setup of jenkins?  it's generally really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying out [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) and loving it. Very little setup required. They seem a bit expensive if you have to go to one of their non-free plans, but all I needed for my project was basic builds and unit test runs. They also have a auto-deploy type functionality which I don't use. It appears you could use it to host your own web application which is constantly up to date

What factors affected my decision:

1. Free
2. Easy to setup (all I had to do was click "approve" on my bitbucket repo)
3. Very little code modifications to make it work(all I had to do was include a local reference of NUnit, rather than relying on the GAC)
4. Awesome integration into bitbucket. Look at this [commit](https://bitbucket.org/earlz/barelymvc/commits/9830c9534bd0ac7479db1796aeb08541fc6aaee5). Notice how Appharbor put a nice comment with a link to the build for it